# Angular 2 RC and ASP.NET Core: CDN doesn't work with index.cshtml but Gulp and script references do work

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, angular

I recently converted an Angular 2 RC project to use ASP.NET Core MVC using Gulp to copy Angular 2 dependencies and reference the files with script references. This worked successfully. When I tried to convert index.cshtml to use CDN my project stopped working. Am I doing the right thing?

**index.cshtml**

```
@{
ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}
@section Styles {
<link rel="stylesheet" href="libs/css/styles.css">
}
@section HeadScripts
{
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/zone.js"></script>
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/reflect-metadata@0.1.3"></script>
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/systemjs@0.19.27/dist/system.src.js"></script>

@*<script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>*@

<script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
<script>
        System.import('app').catch(function (err) { console.error(err); });
 </script>
}

<app>Loading...</app>
```

**systemjs.config.js**

```
(function (global) {

var ngVer = '@2.0.0-rc.4'; 
var routerVer = '@3.0.0-beta.1'; 
var formsVer = '@0.2.0'; 

var map = {
    'app': 'app',

    '@angular': 'https://npmcdn.com/@angular', 
    '@angular/router': 'https://npmcdn.com/@angular/router' + routerVer,
    '@angular/forms': 'https://npmcdn.com/@angular/forms' + formsVer,
    'rxjs': 'https://npmcdn.com/rxjs@5.0.0-beta.6',
    'ts': 'https://npmcdn.com/plugin-typescript@4.0.10/lib/plugin.js',
    'typescript': 'https://npmcdn.com/typescript@1.9.0-dev.20160409/lib/typescript.js'
};

var packages = {
    'app': { main: 'main.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'rxjs': { defaultExtension: 'js' }
};

var ngPackageNames = [
  'common',
  'compiler',
  'core',
  'http',
  'platform-browser',
  'platform-browser-dynamic',
  'upgrade'
];

ngPackageNames.forEach(function (pkgName) {
    map['@angular/' + pkgName] = 'https://npmcdn.com/@angular/' + pkgName + ngVer;
});

ngPackageNames.forEach(function (pkgName) {

    packages['@angular/' + pkgName] = { main: '/bundles/' + pkgName + '.umd.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };

    packages['@angular/'+pkgName] = { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
});

packages['@angular/router'] = { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };

packages['@angular/forms'] = { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };


var config = {
    meta: {
        'typescript': {
            "exports": "ts"
        }
    },
    map: map,
    packages: packages
};

System.config(config);

})(this);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a modification to the CDN for zone.js, closed all documents and closed Visual Studio. When I restarted Visual Studio and ran the app, it took a long time to build but the app ran properly. I think the CDN files hadn't downloaded before. It works now.

**Modified index.cshtml**

```
@{
ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}
@section Styles {
<link rel="stylesheet" href="libs/css/styles.css">
}
@section HeadScripts
{
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/zone.js@0.6.12/dist/zone.js"></script>
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/reflect-metadata@0.1.3"></script>
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/systemjs@0.19.27/dist/system.src.js"></script>

<script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>

<script>
        System.import('app').catch(function (err) { console.error(err); });
</script>
}

<app>Loading...</app>
```

Comment: Thanks, Mark, for posting this in detail. Moving to CDN (instead of copying from node_modules to lib folder) was next on my list. Your solution works and saved me quite some work!